# Div doesn't scroll to bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've got a problem with a `div` which I want to be scrollable.

My menu is in this div (it is full screen) [this is it](http://prnt.sc/dj0g2b). When you hover on an element that has children the menu expands and go out of the screen, that's why I added scrolling, but it doesn't scroll to bottom(it is hiding the last menu).

Here is my CSS and HTML:

```css
.tablet-menu {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 1001;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.tablet-menu.show {
  display: block;
}
.tablet-menu-scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.tablet-menu ul {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.tablet-menu li {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
}
.tablet-menu li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", Times, Georgia, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 4%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tablet-menu">
  <ul class="tablet-menu-scroll">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array ( 'theme_location'=>'new-menu', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' )); ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Sorry for PHP I'm working on WordPress, I wrote a copy of my a menu, without the real Page names.

There it is: [click](http://pastebin.com/p6QudbVT)

I don't really know where the problem is.

Comment: try add attiribute "overflow:scroll;" to '.tablet-menu' instead of 'tablet-menu-scroll'

Comment: Doesn't work ;/

Comment: Remove "display:none;" and "position:fixed;" from ".tablet-menu"

Comment: I want it hidden,till user click on icon,than jquery adds a class to show it.And i want it fixed,because it will go full screen and than once you click it you cannot close it,beacuse close button will be hidden behind the menu.So both options are impossible ;/

Comment: you can use as you want it in my answer below

Comment: Will try it as i get back from work,and will write the result back here,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce padding-top or padding-bottom or both as per your requirement like this:
`.tablet-menu li a {
padding-top: 3%;
padding-bottom: 3%;
}`

Comment: I don't really wanna make my buttons smaller,is there a way to make it scrollable to bottom without reducing the size,or adding other elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
As you want it to be arranged below:
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#show').on('click', function(){
      $('.tablet-menu').addClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.tablet-menu{
display:none;
overflow:scroll;
background:#000;
height:100px;
width:300px;
opacity:0.7;
z-index:1001;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.tablet-menu.show{
display:block;
}
.tablet-menu-scroll{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
.tablet-menu ul{
top:0;
bottom:0;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.tablet-menu li{
color:#FFF;
background:#000;
}
.tablet-menu li a{
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: "Roboto Slab", Times, Georgia, serif;
font-weight:bold;
border-radius:2px;
border-bottom:1px solid white;
position:relative;
display:block;
padding-top:4%;
padding-bottom:4%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tablet-menu">
          <ul class="tablet-menu-scroll">
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
            </ul>
      </div>

<button id="show">Show</button>
```